# What module to choose to post in popular social networking sites in Play! 2.2.0

Tags: facebook, twitter, playframework, social-networking, playframework-2.2

I am pretty new to Play framework. My intention is to create a web application which could allow the users to post to all his social networking accounts from my web app.

I saw a lot of modules (Like SecureSocial, Secure, fbConnect) that can provide me the authentication for the application, but I doubt they would allow me to post content.

1. Is there any module that could suit my needs? Is this idea possible atleast?
2. I am currently planning to use Play 2.2.0, but I see lot of modules are built for Play 1.x. Can I use the same module in Play 2.x as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly common use case, I would recommend [SecureSocial](http://securesocial.ws/) for what you are trying to achieve as it appears to be the most utilised Authentication library for Play.

**Your basic flow would be:**

1. Users on your site authenticate their various social networks using SS. Be sure to configure SS to request any extended permissions you require (in order to post on behalf of the user).
2. Most social APIs will return some kind of auth token, which can be persisted using SS. Note: you will need to implement a custom [UserService](http://securesocial.ws/guide/user-service.html) for persistence.
3. When you want to post on behalf of a user, use the auth token that you have persisted, and hit the relevant social API. Make sure you have error handling in place to deal with expired tokens etc.

Hope this helps!